# Probability to be in a particular state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability

If I have a wavefunction $\psi = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n e^{i \phi_n} | n \rangle$ and $(|n \rangle)$  is a set of orthonormal functions. Is it correct that the probability to be in a state $|k\rangle $ is given by $|a_k|^2$?-So is it really true, that the probability to be in this state is independent of the phase factors $e^{i \phi_n}$ that is DIFFERENT for every $n$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Yes, it is true.

More generally, for any state $\lvert \psi \rangle$, the probability to find it in the state $\lvert\phi\rangle$ is $\lvert \langle \phi \vert \psi \rangle \rvert^2$, and so, since $\lvert \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\phi_n}\rvert^2 = 1$, phases do not influence probability in this case.